# NumericUpDown rejects value

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I've got issues with `NumericUpDown` control. When I try to input a value, the control seems to reject it, despite the value being well withing `Minimum` and `Maximum`.

```
numericField.Hexadecimal = true
numericField.Minimum = 0;
numericField.Maximum = decimal.MaxValue;
```

Now, when I input `FFFFFFF`, it works fine. But adding another `F` will make the control automatically change the value to `0` upon losing focus.

What might be the reason?

Comment: [NumericUpDown.Hexadecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.hexadecimal), Remarks section.

Comment: The reason is that there are several logic inconsistencies in the control with the most limiting painted over by the  remark in the documentation that you are limited to the range of an integer.  If set the Value property via code, you can display values in the range of an Int64 (long).  If you inspect the [ParseEditText method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NumericUpDown.cs,4e30988fde94575b) you will see the logic that limits you to int values.

Comment: You can create a derived control to override most of the issues, but you can use the Up/Down buttons as their usage will use the base ParseEditText method.